# Showing text with single quotes and/or double quotes

Tags: javascript

I have a variable of text, that can have  single quotes or doubles quotes. For example in some cases.

```
`Estado 'mayor`' or  Esto dijo: "Ayer".
```

This text in some cases is taken from a Json, or a variable from database through .spring mvc.

I tried with this:

```
             try{
            descrp='${dataProvider.description}';
        }
        catch(err){
            descrp="${dataProvider.description}";
        }
```

but i have Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

And with:

```
            try {
            alert(data.description);
            }
            catch(err){
             alert(data.description.replace("'", "\'"));    
            }
```

the same error.
Is possible to do something for both cases? (singles quotes and doubles quotes)

Comment: You'll need to use a JSON encoder for those values.  It'll correctly escape embedded quotes (and other things).

Comment: @Pointy I use .ajax() in jquery to get the Json. How i use jquery to encode the json?

Comment: No, I mean in your JSP (or whatever your server-side template language is). Exactly how you do it depends on the server-side environment.

Comment: @Pointy in some cases, i show data  from the server, in others cases, i show data from a json service.  For the json service, i use jquery.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [escape()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp), or convert special characters (quotes) on server side.